Covering window openings during refurbishing
I've got some windows in my new (to me) house (built in the 1930s) that are in pretty rough shape. I'd like to try my hand at refurbishing them myself, and think I have a good idea how to go about it. One thing that doesn't seem to be covered in anything I've read or watched about the process is what to do with the window openings once I've removed the sashes. Since I've never done this before I imagine it'll take me significantly longer per window than it would a professional, and since we're living in the house I don't want to leave the window open while I work on it. What's the best way for me to cover these windows after I remove the sashes so I don't have to feel rushed to finish?
Thanks!

Sheet of exterior plywood screwed on the outside.  Maybe some caulking on top and side edges.
Could use heavy duty drop clothes with a wood frame around the outside, if you want light.
1930s you want to be aware there might be lead paint on the windows.  If so you want to contain all paint pieces/dust you remove.  Not allowing it in the air/ground/kids.

Thanks for your response. So I'm assuming if I also want to sand and paint the window frames the order of operations would be: remove sashes, cover with plywood, refurbish and reinstall sashes, then sand and paint once the plywood can be removed, right?

@BryanCoxwell  With weather not being dependable, would try to as much as possible on the sashes before depending weather to give enough time.  So have them sanded at least.

I’d always finish the painting before re-install.
